# Creating a foggy image

Tags: image-processing

I want to create foggy images like this one (produced with *Adobe Photoshop*):

[image]

Not at least familiar with *Mathematica*'s `Image` processing capabilities, the only thing I am able to do is something like this:

```
Graphics3D[{{Orange, Sphere[{40, 45, 45}, 40]}, Opacity@0.05,
  Raster3D[Table[{1 - x, z}, {x, .1, 1, .01}, {y, .1, 1, .01}, {z, .1, 1, .01}]]},
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 ViewPoint -> {1000, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

What I really want to find is a blurry, fuzzy Lena, hopefully not confined to black & white.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: fog is a nasty thing because it not only blurs, but also reflects light. And both effects are spatially inhomogeneous

Comment: `ImageAdjust[Blend[{image, Blur[image, 50]}, 0.8], -0.4]`

Comment: @RahulNarain I'm somehow perplexed that your nice comment is only a comment.

Comment: @RahulNarain, I think yours looks much better. Please consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: I think the exact analogue to what you did in Photoshop is actually an example in the documentation for [`SetAlphaChannel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAlphaChannel.html). You can get a more 3D effect by using `Raster3D`, but that would probably be overkill.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is my attempt to imagine Lena in a fog

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
r = 200;
r0 = 2;
ker = Table[1/(i^2 + j^2 + r0^2), {i, 0. - r, r}, {j, 0. - r, r}];
ker = ker/Total[ker, 2];
foggy = ImageConvolve[img, ker]
```

[image]

I think Lorentzian kernel is quite good for the fog: it has a sharp peak and broad tails

```
Plot3D[1/(i^2 + j^2 + r0^2), {i, -10 r0, 10 r0}, {j, -10 r0, 10 r0}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

With the ambient lighting (thanks to Simon Woods!):

```
ImageApply[0.7 # + 0.3 &, foggy]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Maybe add a bit of white for scattering of ambient light? `ImageApply[0.7 # + 0.3 &, foggy]`

Comment: thanks @ ybeltukov - I hoped you would step in.

Comment: _Lorentzian_ instead of _Loretzian_ right?

Comment: @Öskå Corrected, thanks! My spellchecker doesn't know such a kernel :)

Comment: +1 for using Lorentz kernels. I love Lorentz kernels for blurring! They are more computationally intensive than Gaussian blurs because the Lorentz kernel is not separable, but the heavy-tailed properties give a much nicer image in certain circumstances, and this is no exception.

Comment: I didn't find much information about the Lorentzian kernel, would you have some references?

Answer (score 11):

Does this work for you? (otherwise I'll delete it and let the imaging experts handle this)

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
```

Then:

```
res = ImageConvolve[img, BoxMatrix[8]/289.];

ImageAssemble[{img, res}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Your answer must stay. First time I encountered `BoxMatrix`. Lena has become blurry und fuzzy. Is she foggy? Maybe a certain amount of randomness should be injected?

Comment: @eldo Thanks. So many functions in *Mathematica*, it's impossible to know them all. Nice idea about the randomness.

Answer (score 11):

This uses [Radon/InverseRadon](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Radon.html) transforms adding to Mathematica in version 8.

The core of the logic is in this line:

```
ImageAdjust@InverseRadon[Radon[img, {n, n}, Method -> method],
   "Filter" -> inverseMethod, "CutoffFrequency" -> cutOffFrequency]
```

By controlling the cutoff frequency, methods used, and applying your own custom  backprojection method, you can achieve many different foggy effects.

[image]

code:

```
Manipulate[
 ImageAdjust@InverseRadon[Radon[img, {n, n}, Method -> method],
    "Filter" -> inverseMethod, "CutoffFrequency" -> cutOffFrequency]
 ,
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{cutOffFrequency, 1, Text@Row[{Subscript[Style["f", Italic, 11], 
      Style["c", Italic, 11]]}]}, .01, 1, 0.01,
      ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
   },
   {Control[{{method, "Radon", "Radon method"}, {"Radon", "Hough"}, 
       ControlType -> PopupMenu, ImageSize -> All}]},
   {
    Control[{
      {inverseMethod, # Cos[# Pi] &, "Inverse Radon method"},
      {(1 + Cos[# Pi])/2 & -> "Hann",
       1 & -> "Rectangular",
       # & -> "Ramp-Lak",
       # Sin[# 2 Pi] & -> "Sin Ramp",
       # Cos[# Pi] & -> "Cosine Ramp",
       ((1 - 0.16)/2 - (1/2) Cos[# Pi] + 0.08 Cos[# 2 Pi]) & -> "Blackman",
       (0.355768 - 0.487396 Cos[# Pi] + 0.144232 Cos[# 2 Pi]) - 
         0.012604 Cos[# 3 Pi] & -> "Nuttal window",
       Sinc[#] & -> "Shepp-Logan",
       (.54 + .46 Cos[# Pi]) & -> "Hamming",
       Sqrt[1/(1 + #^(2))] & -> "Butterworth order 1",
       Sqrt[1/(1 + #^(4))] & -> "Butterworth order 2",
       Sqrt[1/(1 + #^(6))] & -> "Butterworth order 3",
       None -> "No filter"},
      ControlType -> PopupMenu, ImageSize -> All}]
    }}],
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (
   n = 200;(*image size to display, smaller is faster*)
   img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks @ Nasser :) Certainly much more than I asked for. Also, some images produced wizh your method are so beautyful.

Comment: Excellent use of Radon transform! +1